# Dotnet 6 - Azure Functions v4 - Route parameter does not work

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0

I am running dotnet 6 & Azure Functions V4.

I specify a route via the route parameter of Http triggered function. While running the function app locally, I get the URL output on command prompt as follows. however, when i try to hit this url from postman or even swagger, I get a 404 not found.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunHttp(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "account/policyAssignments")] HttpRequest request)

http://localhost:7000/api/account/policyAssignments
```

If i say route = null and just use the function name for the Url, it works. I am not sure what am i missing.

```
[FunctionName("policyAssignments")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunHttp(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest request)

http://localhost:7000/api/policyAssignments
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I got results as expected, I have followed below process:
Firstly, I have created a .NET 6 with http azure function then my code is as below:

**Function.cs:**

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace FunctionApp35{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
      public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "account/policyAssignments")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**local.settings.josn:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then when I run I get below as output :

[image]

Then when i run in postman :

[image]

Please try to use above code and it will work for you as it worked for me.